# change year in date irrespective of date format using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to only change year in the date irrespective of date format. For example if date=05/20/2019 0r 05-20-2019 then it should change to 05/20/2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `DateSerial()` to replace the Year component.

```
Call SetLocale("en-us")
Dim oldDate: oldDate = CDate("05/20/2019")
Dim newDate: newDate = DateSerial(2015, Month(oldDate), Day(oldDate)
```